# Unhide div when checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to create a responsive navbar, so when you click a hidden checkbox the content unhides.

The problem is, I can't get the "checked" css to actually pick up and do anything.

Example to run here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNvvZy

**CSS:**

```
#nav-hidden{background: red; display: none;}
#navigation-mobile{display:none;}

/* DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
        #navigation-mobile {display: block;}
        #menu-toggle:checked ~ #nav-hidden {
            opacity: 1;
            height: 100vh;
            visibility: visible;
        }

        .label-toggle {
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            float: right;
        }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navigation-mobile">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
      <label for="menu-toggle" class="label-toggle"></label>
    </input>
    <div id="nav-hidden">
        <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, on the original state you have:

```css
#nav-hidden{display:none;}
```

So, you'll need to reset it on `:checked` state:

```css
#menu-toggle:checked ~ #nav-hidden {display:block;}
```

Also want to point out that, you can animate `height`, `opacity`, `visibility` etc., but you can't animate `display` property.

The `<input>` element is a self-closing tag, you can do `<input>` or `<input />`, but you can't do `<input></input>`.

```css
#nav-hidden {
  display: none;
}
#menu-toggle:checked ~ #nav-hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation-mobile">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
  <label for="menu-toggle" class="label-toggle"></label>
  <div id="nav-hidden">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, appreciated :)